# Use DotNetNuke modules inside ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, navigation, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

We have two websites: a DNN site and an ASP.NET MVC site. We want to have a global navigation system across both of them. Right now, the DNN site is using [DDRMenu](http://dnnddrmenu.codeplex.com/) for the navigation. Is there a way to get the html rendered from this exposed as a web service or something to include it on the MVC site? Or maybe there's a better way of sharing a common navigation across these two sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DDRMenu just builds its menu from the Tabs table in the DNN database.
You could just set up a WebService that gives you the menu structure and you could rebuild your MVC navigation based on this.

```
  SELECT [TabID]
  ,[TabOrder]  // Order in the menu
  ,[PortalID]
  ,[TabName]  // Menu name
  ,[IsVisible]
  ,[ParentId]
  ,[IconFile]  // image
  ,[DisableLink]  // Is the link clickable?
  ,[Title]
  ,[Description]
  ,[IsDeleted]
  ,[Url]
  ,[IconFileLarge]
  ,[ContentItemID]
  ,[Level]
  ,[TabPath]  // path to where the page exists
  FROM [dnnDB].[dbo].[Tabs] 
  Where IsDeleted = 0 and IsVisible = 1
```